# How often is the Silverlight Access policy accessed?

Tags: silverlight, http, sockets, request

As you may well know, it is required to host an access policy 
(clientaccesspolicy.xml) on your web server if you want SL apps
to perform HTTP requests, or you need to host an access server
on port 943 for socket connections.

My app makes many short requests and latency is important. I want
to know if this access policy file is accessed once for every
new HTTP request or is it accessed for the first request and have
its result cached on the client. It would be quite costly for me
to have two web requests (one for the policy, one for the HTTP GET)
for each HTTP request I create.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to test this is to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/) and watch for requests to the policy file.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(VS.95).aspx) also specifies that the cross-domain policy file is requested only once per application session. This means that the runtime will only request it once and store the result in memory for the silverlight session.